# Javascript: Select Form Changes "Value" in Textbox but Does not update when reselecting from same dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, select, onchange, getelementbyid

It's a simple thing but for this newbie, it ain't workin'.

Just want to select one of the items from the dropdown and it automatically updates the text box in  and  divs.

When I do with the current code, it only shows "if3" for any of the selections.

I tried using else if but either I have the code wrong or it shouldn't work that way.

Your feedback is appreciated.

I looked around this whole site and did not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    function phoneNumber()
    {
var officeaddress=document.getElementById("officeaddress");

if (officeaddress.options="936 Broadway")
document.getElementById("enterphone").value="if1";
document.getElementById("enterfax").value="if1";
if(officeaddress.options="729 Seventh Avenue")
document.getElementById("enterphone").value="if2";
document.getElementById("enterfax").value="if2";
if(officeaddress.options="155 East 56th Street")
document.getElementById("enterphone").value="if3";
document.getElementById("enterfax").value="if3";


}


</script>


</head>

<body>

 <div class="textforms3">
       <select name="officeaddress" id="officeaddress" onchange="phoneNumber()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Approved Main Office Address 
</option>
            <option value="936 Broadway" >936 Broadway</option>
            <option value="729 Seventh Avenue">729 Seventh Avenue</option>
            <option value="155 East 56th Street">155 East 56th Street</option>
      </select>
    </div>

<div class="enterphone"> 
       <input name="enterphone" type="text" id="enterphone" size="20" class="inputstyle" value="Phone Number"   />
       </div>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly in your `if` statements you use one `=` which assigns values. You need to use `===` for testing values (look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for more info on equality operators). also I would test for the value of the select or the value of the selected option. Something like this.

```
function phoneNumber() {

    var officeaddress = document.getElementById("officeaddress").options[document.getElementById("officeaddress").selectedIndex].value;

    if (officeaddress === "936 Broadway") {
      document.getElementById("enterphone").value = "if1";
      document.getElementById("enterfax").value = "if1";
    }

    if(officeaddress === "729 Seventh Avenue") {
      document.getElementById("enterphone").value = "if2";
      document.getElementById("enterfax").value = "if2";
    }

    if(officeaddress === "155 East 56th Street" ){
      document.getElementById("enterphone").value = "if3";
      document.getElementById("enterfax").value = "if3";
    }
}
```

Your code was also missing curly braces `{}` round your `if` statements and some basic formatting.

Comment: Why use select.options[select.selectedIndex].value instead of select.value?

Comment: @Mark Walters, you rock man thanks. This worked perfectly. And thanks for the reference on equality operators. I had a feeling it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The html you have pasted does not have any element with id 'enterfax'. So even after suggested code correction and all the formatting, this will break:

```
document.getElementById("enterfax").value="if1";
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

This is JS equivalent of a null pointer exception. You are basically trying to do null.value which is incorrect. Make sure that whatever you access programmatically exists.

Comment: You are right it was not in there but I didn't think it mattered. My focus was to get feedback on the javascript. Thanks Rajat.